# How to log crontab activities

Tags: cron

I have crontab running 3 executions every hour. Those scripts take a while running - sometimes more than 10 minutes.

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/uptime >> /local/log.txt
0 * * * * /usr/bin/php5 /local/file_1.php
0 * * * * /usr/bin/php5 /local/file_2.php
0 * * * * /usr/bin/php5 /local/file_3.php
```

Is there a way to add execution time into log.txt?

Comment: Are your commands supposed to produce any output?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to append the following to your lines:

```
; echo "script XXX ended at: $(date)" >> /tmp/mylog
```

Like:

```
0 * * * * /usr/bin/php5 /local/file_1.php; echo "script file_1.php ended at: $(date)" >> /tmp/mylog
0 * * * * /usr/bin/php5 /local/file_2.php; echo "script file_2.php ended at: $(date)" >> /tmp/mylog
0 * * * * /usr/bin/php5 /local/file_3.php; echo "script file_3.php ended at: $(date)" >> /tmp/mylog
```

Since you know when the script is started (every whole hour), you can see rather easy how long it ran by looking at the date when it finished.

Another way is to alter the php scripts to measure the execution time and to write it to a custom logfile from the script itself.

If you are using Solaris you can have a look in `/var/cron/log` where start and end times are logged.

Comment: Thank you, Lambert. Apparently it did not ran. Any idea on how to check why it didn't wen throught? I'm on Ubuntu

Comment: Please explain what did not ran. The complete script, or the logging, does it produce error messages? Please look in `/var/log/syslog` for messages according `cron`.